# Approximating sine function with Neural Network and ReLU

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, regression, keras

I am trying to approximate a sine function with a neural network (Keras).

Yes, I read the related posts :)

- [Link 1](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-role-of-the-activation-function-in-a-neural-network/answer/Sebastian-Raschka-1)
- [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565115/approximating-function-with-neural-network)
- [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269091/mlp-neural-network-wont-learn)

Using four hidden neurons with sigmoid and an output layer with linear activation works fine.

But there are also settings that provide results that seem strange to me.

Since I am just started to work with I am interested in what and why things happen, but I could not figure that out so far.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
np.random.seed(7)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import pylab as pl
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

X = np.linspace(0.0 , 2.0 * np.pi, 10000).reshape(-1, 1)
Y = np.sin(X)

x_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
#y_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1.0, 1.0))
y_scaler = MinMaxScaler()

X = x_scaler.fit_transform(X)
Y = y_scaler.fit_transform(Y)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=X.shape[1], kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
# model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=X.shape[1], kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
# model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=X.shape[1], kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae'])

model.fit(X, Y, epochs=500, batch_size=32, verbose=2)

res = model.predict(X, batch_size=32)

res_rscl = y_scaler.inverse_transform(res)

Y_rscl = y_scaler.inverse_transform(Y)

pl.subplot(211)
pl.plot(res_rscl, label='ann')
pl.plot(Y_rscl, label='train')
pl.xlabel('#')
pl.ylabel('value [arb.]')
pl.legend()
pl.subplot(212)
pl.plot(Y_rscl - res_rscl, label='diff')
pl.legend()
pl.show()
```

This is the result for four hidden neurons (ReLU) and linear output activation. 
[image: 4 hidden neurons (ReLU), output activation: linear]

Why does the result take the shape of the ReLU?

Does this have something to do with the output normalization?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things here:

1. Your network is really shallow and small. Having only 4 neurons with `relu` makes a case when a couple of this neurons are completely saturated highly possible. This is probably why your network result looks like that. Try `he_normal` or `he_uniform` as initializer to overcome that.
2. In my opinion your network is too small for this task. I would definitely increase both depth and width of your network by intdoucing more neurons and layers to your network. In case of `sigmoid` which has a similiar shape to a `sin` function this might work fine - but in case of `relu` you really need a bigger network.

Comment: yep, just giving the above code 40 ReLu HUs gives a much nicer fit: http://imgur.com/a/yhTqw

Answer (score 2):

Try adding more hidden layers, each with more hidden units. I used this code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=X.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=X.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
```

and got these results:

[image]